# Call willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation programmatically in iOS 6

Tags: ios, orientation

In my viewController that has other viewControllers, in iOS 5, it acts all right because it calls `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method. If I rotate the device, iOS will call `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, and the app acts right, but when the app first launches, it does not. Then I try to call `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` in viewWillAppear, but it does not help.

How can I call `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` programmatically or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is one of several methods that should only be called by the device. The only thing that is special about it is when it is called, so if you extract its functionality to another method you should be able to call that functionality as you will (in this case, in `viewWillAppear`).

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self prepareToRotate];
}

-(void)prepareToRotate {
    // existing functionality goes here
}
```

Note that if you use `toInterfaceOrientation` or `duration` you should also include them as parameters in `prepareToRotate`.